# What does this mean: O(n) steps and O(1) space?

Tags: computer-science

What does O(1) space mean? I understand that O(n) steps is like the order of magnitude of calculations an algorithm/program makes, but don't know what the O(n) space is.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

O(1) space means that the memory required by the algorithm is constant, i.e. does not depend on the size of the input.

O(n) space means that the memory required by the algorithm has (in the worst case) the same order of magnitude as the size of the input.

**Edit**:
Adding two examples:

- Bubblesort requires O(1) space.
- Mergesort requires O(n) space.

Comment: so then basically a recursive call would usually be the O(n) space and an iterative process would be O(1) since you're not waiting for a recursive call(s) to finish?

Comment: Added two common examples. Well, you can't really find general rules about recursive vs iterative algorithm complexities (but it's probably hard -if not impossible- for a recursive algorithm to have O(1) space complexity).

Comment: if your recursive call used new variables every time it was called then yes it would be O(n) space. If your iterative process instantiated new variables in a loop without releasing then it too would O(n). It all depends on how you design and code the algorithm.

Comment: @Nikhil: Actually, recursive calls always consume space for activation records, so even if you don't have local variables, complexity wouldn't be O(1).

Comment: unless, of course, you're using tail recursion.  If you have a tail-recursive function with no local variables, then it'll be O(1) space.

Comment: Would not Bubble sort also be O(n) since the thing (array) your trying to sort can vary when speaking generally. So if I can a function that took in an array of variable size, then I would assume space complexity would be O(n)

Comment: @arias_JC The answer is talking about how much extra space the sorting algorithm requires. We always need O(n) space to store the input in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially "O(n) steps and O(1) space" would mean that the number of steps the algoritm performs scale linearly (O(n)) with the number of items, but the amount of memory it takes is constant.